# How to limit query execution time in SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server, timeout

I am executing a query and stored procedure against MS SQL Server. Both php script and sql server reside on the same server. Sometimes it takes too much time to execute and the PHP script crashes. However SQL Server continues executing the queries in the background.

How can I force SQL Server to stop any queries which take more than X seconds to execute?

Comment: Why does this query take so long to run??  When the php script "crashes" I assume you mean it times out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a server level setting, see Microsoft [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040(v=sql.105).aspx).

> 1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
> 2. Click the Connections node.
> 3. Under Remote server connections, in the Remote query timeout box, type or select a value from 0 through 2,147,483,647 to set the maximum number seconds for SQL Server to wait before timing out.

Comment: "remote query timeout" affects only queries over linked server in SQL Server. As Microsoft says: "his value has no effect on queries received by the Database Engine." (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177457(v=sql.105))

Answer (score 0):

Also you can increase the execution time of php via **max_execution_time** setting in your **php.ini** file or using the function **set_time_limit** in your php file

Answer (score -1):

There's a configuration parameter in PHP: mssql.timeout which defaults to 60 seconds and limits time to execute queries. After this time the MSSQL PHP driver will abort the query and report query timeout error.

But there's no such thing as "query timeout" in SQL Server itself :-)